# Copy folders to newly created folder and append

Tags: python

This is the first part that works , basically created 3 new mandatory folders (1,2,3) in the main TEST directory and if user wants to add any new one they can do so.  This is Python_1

```
import os
root_path = r"C:\TEST"
list_dir = []
while True:
    userinput1 = raw_input("Enter the name for Folder1, Folder2, Folder3:")
    list_dir.append(userinput1)
    userinput2 = None
#ask user to respond 'yes' or 'no' as to whether they want to add another directory
    while userinput2 != "yes" and userinput2 != "no":
        userinput2 = raw_input("Would you like to add another directory? yes/no: ")
    if userinput2 == "no":
        break
for directory in list_dir:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path, directory))
print 'New directories have been created'
```

Now I need a new script that does the following: 
Creates new main folder WORKING within TEST, and copy all folders created in Python_1 into newly created WORKING folder with appended   _working to the name of the copied folders.

Any ideas? 
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

root_path = r"C:\TEST"
new_main_folder = 'WORKING'

list_dir = next(os.walk(root_path))[1]  # Folder1, Folder2, Folder3 from Python_1

# Creates C:\TEST\WORKING
new_root_path = os.path.join(root_path, new_main_folder)
os.mkdir(new_root_path)

for directory in list_dir:
    src = os.path.join(root_path, directory)  # C:\TEST\Folder[1,2,3]
    dest = os.path.join(new_root_path, directory + '_working')  # C:\TEST\WORKING\Folder[1,2,3]_working
    # or
    # renamed_folder = directory + '_' + new_main_folder.lower()
    # dest = os.path.join(new_root_path, renamed_folder)
    shutil.copytree(src, dest)
```

Comment: Thanks Titan, it does create Working folder but for some reason it does not copy created folders from Python_1 into Working folder.

Comment: I think list_dir = [] is en empty list and lines below are never executed. How to fix this?

Comment: @user7380301, In the comment after `list_dir = []` is shown `Folder1, Folder2, Folder3 from Python_1`. That means that in the `list_dir` you need to provide names of folders from `Python_1`. From your question it is not clear for me whether you want to provide these folders names by yourself or would you like me to add a code which can find these folders automaticaly and update the answer?

Comment: No, you do not provide names, created folders from script 1 should be automatically found and copied into newly created Working folder.Thank you very much!

Comment: @user7380301, Check now pls

Comment: Error:  for directory in list_dir:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: not sure about this line  list_dir = list_dir.remove(new_main_folder) , why remove?

Comment: Is there a folders inside `test` directory? `list_dir = next(os.walk(root_path))[1]` returs `Folder1, Folder2, Folder3 and WORKING`; `list_dir = list_dir.remove(new_main_folder)` removes `WORKING` from this list because you do not need to copy `WORKING` What verison of python you have? 2 or 3?

Comment: I got it, ... it`s weird, when I delete that REMOVE line it kind of works, all files are copied including Working folder, but with REMOVE line it gives me error mentiondd above

Comment: yes, there are folders in TEST directory created previously from script one

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: I reorganized the code. No need to remove anything any more. Check it pls.

Comment: Great! Works perfectly. Thank you very much Sir!